# 301 редирект с категории на другую категорию по условию

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день.

Как получить название категории(или таксономии) по урлу и заменить ее на другую?
(можно сказать 301 редирект)

Например:
есть урла -  `http://название_сайта/категория-1/casumo-casino-reviews`
нужно заменить на `http://название_сайта/тут_заменить_на_новую_категорию(категория-2)/casumo-casino-reviews`

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего воспользоваться плагином [Redirection](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/).

Или functions.php добавить:

```
add_action('init', 'do_rewrite');
function do_rewrite() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^категория-1/', 'index.php?category_name=категория-2','top');
}
```

Но с подкатегорией у заменяемой категории - работать не будет, скорее всего - ни первое, ни второе решение.

Comment: Возможно плагин хорошее решение, но в моем случае нужно именно в шаблоне через условие сделать.

Comment: очередной заказчик с плагинофобией? ))

Comment: можно .htaccess поправить - устроит?

Comment: нет, просто там много редиректов и по этому самый оптимальный вариант сделать в шаблонах.

Comment: сайт на nginx + нужно в шаблоне через условие)

Comment: лучше бы в nginx, но ладно. сейчас

Comment: а вот это /casumo-casino-reviews - подкатегория еще одна?

Comment: это может быть и подкатегория и есть посты, мне нужно как то заменить только второй путь после урл, все что там дальше будет не важно.

Comment: Ответ дополнил, но сильно похоже на нерешаемую проблему.

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду пробовать, чуть позже отвечу, получилось или нет

Comment: А кстати, почему не поменять просто slug у категория1 на категория2? В аминке?)

Comment: есть шаблон  категория1 и категория2. И нужно если шаблон категория1 - то так и оставляем если категория2 то меняем slug с категория1 на категория2. Не спрашивай даже зачем)))

Answer (score 0):

```
$test= str_replace('/test/', '/test-2/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$current_url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $test;
if(stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/test/')){
     header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
     header("Location: ". $current_url); 
     exit();
}
```